# Exclude specific tag or tags from related posts?

Tags: tags

How can i exclude the display of a specific tag or tags on the results of related posts?

this is the code http://pastebin.com/Ksh7NY7g

```
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Related Posts Function
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

function ag_get_related_post_args($id){

    global $relatedcatargs, $relatedargs;

    $rel_tagnames = '';
    $rel_catnames = '';

    if ( !($relatednumber = of_get_option('of_related_number') ) ) { $relatednumber = '2'; } else { $relatednumber = of_get_option('of_related_number'); } 

    // Get related post tag names
    $rel_tags = get_the_tags($id);

    if ($rel_tags) {
        // Get list of tag names and set arguments for loop
    foreach($rel_tags as $rel_tag) {
          $rel_tagnames .= $rel_tag->slug . ',';
        }
        $relatedargs = array(
          'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
          'tag' => $rel_tagnames,
          'post__not_in' => array($id),
          'showposts' => $relatednumber,
          'orderby' => 'rand'
        );
    }

    // Get list of category names and set arguments for loop
    $post_cats = wp_get_post_categories($id);

    foreach($post_cats as $post_cat) {
      $rel_catnames .= get_cat_name( $post_cat ) .',';
    }

    $relatedcatargs = array(
      'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
      'category__in' => $post_cats,
      'post__not_in' => array($id),
      'showposts' => $relatednumber,
      'orderby' => 'rand'
    );

}

function load_custom_scripts() {
    global $wp_version;

    if (version_compare($wp_version, '3.4.2', '>')) {
        wp_register_script('my-jquery-ui', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js', 'jquery');
        } else {
        wp_register_script('my-jquery-ui', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js', 'jquery');
    } 


    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-jquery-ui' );
}

add_action('admin_init', 'load_custom_scripts');
```

```
global $relatedargs, $relatedcatargs;
// Query Posts by tag
$my_query = new WP_Query($relatedargs);

//If there are posts
if( $my_query->have_posts()) { ?>

<!-- Related Posts -->
<div class="relatedposts">
  <h3><?php _e('Related Posts', 'framework'); ?></h3>

    <?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

  <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" class="one_col half">
    <div class="featuredinner">
          <h2><?php 
              if (strlen($post->post_title) > 40) {
                  echo substr(the_title($before = '', $after = '', FALSE), 0, 80) . '...'; 
              } else {
                  the_title();
              }  ?>                      
              <span class="date"><?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?> | <?php echo get_the_author(); ?></span></h2>
              <div class="featuredoverlay"></div>
              <?php the_post_thumbnail('blogonecol', array('class' => 'scale-with-grid')); /* post thumbnail settings configured in functions.php */ ?>
    </div>
  </a>

    <?php endwhile;  ?>

  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<?php } wp_reset_query(); // end if there are posts and reset the query ?>
```

Comment: Please edit your code into the question.

Comment: i tried but see right now who it shows on post with <pre></pre>

Comment: That won't happen if you use the code formatting tools provided by the editor. Look for the `{}` button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Codex has [almost exactly what you are asking](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'movie_genre',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'action', 'comedy' )
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'actor',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => array( 103, 115, 206 ),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

You just need to remove the couple of parts you don't need, and of course change the `post_type` and taxonomy details to fit your data.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => array( 103, 115, 206 ), // change these
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Best I can do with the minimal detail provided in the question.

Based on new information in an edit to the question:

The `'tag' => $rel_tagnames,` pattern you are using is **deprecated**. You should be using a `tax_query` as above. Since you are already including a list of tags to search, you shouldn't need to exclude any. When you include specific tags, others are *de facto* excluded. So what you would want is this:

```
if ($rel_tags) {
    $relatedargs = array(
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        'post__not_in' => array($id),
        'showposts' => $relatednumber,
        'orderby' => 'rand'
    );
    // Get list of tag names and set arguments for loop
    foreach($rel_tags as $rel_tag) {
      // exclude some tags
      $excluded_tags = array (1,2,3);
      if (in_array($rel_tag->term_id,$excluded_tags)) continue;
      $rel_tagnames[] = $rel_tag->term_id;
    }
    $relatedargs['tax_query'] = array(
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => $rel_tagnames,
      )
    )
}

// the rest of your code
```

I changed that to use `ID`s instead of slugs. It is probably more efficient to search those than the slugs, though I haven't benchmarked it, and converted to a `tax_query`. Tags are excluded when you build the "include" list, instead of trying to do that in the query itself.

Why does your function set `globals` instead of just `return`ing data?

Comment: and where exactly on my code i add this?

Comment: You need to work the `tax_query` part into your `$relatedargs` arguments for your query. As you didn't post what `$relatedargs` already looks like I couldn't really do that for you.

Comment: i update my post check